# My EJB application that is running fine with JDK 1.6 and WebLogic 10c, but encountering an error when trying to run it with JDK 11 and WebLogic 14c

Tags: ejb

I'm currently facing an issue with my EJB application that is running fine with JDK 1.6 and WebLogic 10c, but encountering an error when trying to run it with JDK 11 and WebLogic 14c. The error message I'm getting is "ejbc couldn't invoke compiler".

I've tried troubleshooting the issue but haven't been able to find a solution. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue or has experience with migrating EJB applications from JDK 1.6 to JDK 11 and WebLogic 14c.

Here are some details about my setup:

JDK version: JDK 11
WebLogic version: WebLogic 14c
EJB application version: 2.1
Error message: "ejbc couldn't invoke compiler"
I've already checked the EJB application code and configuration for any compatibility issues with JDK 11 and WebLogic 14c, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

Changed the xml declaration in ejb-jar.xml